# Calling parent page method from child control in C#

Tags: c#

I have a child UserControl which is dynamically loaded into a parent page.

```
ChildControl childcontrol = this.LoadControl("") as ChildControl;
```

I have to call one of the methods in the parent page from this childUserControl. How do we do that?

Thanks

Comment: ASP.Net I'd guess from `LoadControl` and `Page`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't write a control that relies on a method being on the page, so the best thing to do would be to expose and handle an event from the child control. Add the following to your child control:

```
public event OnSomethingHandler Something;
public delegate void OnSomethingHandler(ChildControl sender);
```

Then when you want to fire the page method in question, fire off the event:

```
public void FireParentMethod()
{
    if (Something != null)
    {
        Something(this);
    }
}
```

The all you need to do is handle the event on the page (in markup or in code as follows):

```
childUserControl.Something+= 
    new ChildControl.OnSomethingHandler(ChildControl_OnSomething);
```

And add the handler to the code behind:

```
protected void ChildControl_OnSomething(ChildControl sender)
{
    FirePageMethod();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely the way to do it. Technically, however, you could do what the OP asked. :)

Comment: @Esteban Araya - You already gave that answer :) so there was no point in me duplicating it. But I'd rather give an answer that encourages good pracise as apposed to braking basic design rules.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the parent of the control as the specific type of your page and then call the method.